# Как заставить css меню открываться справа?

Tags: html, css

Сверстал код менюшки:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.position-span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">О нас</a>
  <a href="#">Сервис</a>
  <a href="#">Клиенты</a>
  <a href="#">Контакты</a>
</div>

<h2>Какая-то надпись</h2>
<p>Какой-то текст.</p>
<span class="position-span" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Как заставить её раскрываться справа-налево, а не слева-направо?
Появление реализовано элементарно через ширину, в js - присваивается значение width 250 при клике на кнопку. При клике на закрытие width=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе просто надо в **.sidenav**

`left: 0;` заменить на `right: 0;`
И можно добавить туда же `overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;`, чтобы буквы не скакали при открытии и закрытии меню

Comment: И как я сам не додумался.. За это и люблю этот сайт, мелочи не замечаю, помогают быстро) Спасибо!